# 'react-native' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: react-native

I recently started with react-native. I install it using the tutorial on the Facebook site and everything works well for a day or two until this message comes up:

```
'react-native' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Nothing works except uninstalling everything and starting all over again. The environments are ok and work (npm, choco, etc.). I have also tried removing and adding react-native to environment variables, restarting, and running cmd in administrator mode, but nothing so far. I should add that I use windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: `npm install -g react-native-cli`  works in most of the cases. Do remember to restart the command prompt to get `react-native` command working.

Comment: Restart command prompt was the key

Comment: after installing `npm install -g react-native-cli` dont forget to restart the cmd

Comment: for me the issue was not havig a jdk installed, running `choco install -y nodejs.install openjdk8` solved this

Answer (score 149):

I had the same issue and tried the following but didnt work

1. Adding npm path to my Environment variables; both system and user
2. Re install npm and react-native-cli

Both didn't work for me, im using Windows 10;

Solution that worked for me is to install react-native-cli globally
You can install it globally by using the below command:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Answer (score 47):

You can simply use `npx react-native <command>` it will work

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Please help me to understand what is the magic npx is playing and react-native's commands starts working?

Comment: @NarendraChandratre npx is just a package executor, so `npx react-native run-ios` allows you to use execute react-native without downloading the whole cli

Answer (score 11):

`npm install -g react-native-cli`

But dont forget to restart command promprt

Answer (score 9):

You need to setup the npm path in your environment variables. Please look at the images down below

[image]

Then follow the command : for installing -g ( global ) for cli in your system

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Answer (score 9):

Your system or user environment PATH variable was edited, you can uninstall NodeJs and install it again or add the below path to the end of PATH variable into user variables the restart the Windows :

C:\Users\[USER-NAME]\AppData\Roaming\npm

this should work.

Answer (score 7):

I get the same error right off the bat on Windows 10 running in cmd window in adminstrator mode, however there is also a bash shell version of react-native that worked for me in a git bash window.

```
cmd:----------------------------------------------
C:\Users\David\Documents\react>where react-native
C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm\react-native
C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm\react-native.cmd

C:\Users\David\Documents\react>react-native init AwesomeProject
'react-native' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


git bash:----------------------------------------
David@CYBER-PC ~/Documents/react
$ react-native init AwesomeProject
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in        c:\Users\David\Documents\react\AwesomeProject
Installing react-native package from npm...
Setting up new React Native app in  c:\Users\David\Documents\react\AwesomeProject
AwesomeProject@0.0.1 c:\Users\David\Documents\react\AwesomeProject`-- react@15.3.1

To run your app on iOS:
   cd c:\Users\David\Documents\react\AwesomeProject
   react-native run-ios
   - or -
   Open   c:\Users\David\Documents\react\AwesomeProject\ios\AwesomeProject.xcodeproj in Xcode
   Hit the Run button
To run your app on Android:
   Have an Android emulator running (quickest way to get started), or a device connected
   cd c:\Users\David\Documents\react\AwesomeProject
   react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 6):

`npm install -g react-native-cli`

Comment: Please try to avoid code only answers by adding some explanation of why your code is the solution to the question. Remember this answer could help someone else in the future and the more information the better.

Answer (score 6):

I had to add the `%APPDATA%\npm` folder to my PATH on Windows 10. Global modules are installed there.

Answer (score 5):

If uninstalling and installing again the `npm` did not work on you, try adding `%APPDATA%\npm` to path (Environment variables) then **quick reboot/restart**. System Reboot should really be part of the process. This worked on my end.

**Install** :

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

**Uninstall** :

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are following the [getting started guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) for Windows/Android, they recommend installing nodejs via Chocolatey. But Chocolatey likes to have administrator rights when it installs things. If you're just a regular user, this seems to interfere with how npm installs `react-native-cli`. In my case, the `react-native` command was only recognized when I launched a command prompt as admin.

What I did to fix:

1. launched command prompt as admin
2. uninstalled `react-native-cli` globally: `npm uninstall -g react-native-cli`
3. uninstalled `nodejs` via Chocolatey: `choco uninstall nodejs`

Now, as a regular user without admin rights:

4. installed `nodejs` via the [nodejs website](https://nodejs.org/) (not Chocolatey)
5. installed `react-native-cli` globally: `npm install -g react-native-cli`

Answer (score 3):

I uninstalled node.js and then reinstalled it, and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

1. just uninstall the `node.js` and reinstall it..
2. then install the `cli` package typing command

`npm install -g react-native-cli..`

now you are ready to make your project.

To make project open a folder from your drive wherever your folder is located.

Then type command

```
react-native init albums
```

it will create a project for you inside your directory.

Comment: you took that Udemy Course too.?

Answer (score 2):

None of the above mentioned solutions worked for me. What did work was to remove nodejs, and reinstall it via [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install) with the following command:

```
PS > choco install -y nodejs.install python2 jdk8

> npm install -g react-native-cli
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\react-native ->       
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js
+ react-native-cli@2.0.1
added 41 packages from 15 contributors in 4.528s
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem also becuase I restored my files from a previous OS installation. My problem was a wrong **prefix** in my **C:\Users\user_name\.npmrc** file.

Run `npm config list` and make sure that all your npm config variables are leading to the correct file paths. Delete the .npmrc file if you want have it to go back to the defaults. That's what I did and **react-native** command is working for me again.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

use node.js stable version or recommended version.

Answer (score 1):

i have no clear idea but below steps worked for me.

1. delete Node Modules
2. Uninstall react-native cli. This is Recommended in the react-native [Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started)

"*If you previously installed a global react-native-cli package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues.*"

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

3. clean gradlew. in your project folder, go to the android folder by typing `cd android` 
   and run `gradlew clean`
4. move back to your project  folder `cd ..`, then run

   npx react-native run-android

these steps worked for me. took some time when running first time.

Answer (score 1):

Use npx before your command

```
  npx react-native
```

Not just

```
  react-native
```

Answer (score 1):

installing separately `npm install -g react-native-cli` is unnecessary if you initialized your project with npx react-native init AwesomeProject as it will automatically installing `react-native-cli` as well locally inside your project node_modules directory.

So, in case you initialized new project using 'npx' command, you should use `'npx react-native run-android'` to run your AwesomeProject, otherwise simply run this command `'react-native run-android'` if you initialized using `'react-native init AwesomeProject'`, but you need to install CLI globally.

So, this is the summary:

CLI Locally

```
'npx react-native init AwesomeProject'
'npx react-native run-android'
```

CLI Globally

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
npm -g install react-native-cli
npm -g install react-native
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

On window 10, nodejs>11 global node libraries seems to be installed in C:\Users\your_user_name.npm-global. So you need to set the variable to point to that path

Answer (score 0):

I had problems because of this strange mistake.

I checked to see if it was globally loaded again

I didn't delete all packages

I even deleted C:\Users[USER-NAME]\AppData\Roaming\ npm manually, but there was no solution.

The only thing that is the solution is to use the **current** version of **node.js.**

Answer (score 0):

uninstall nodejs completely(restart your pc) and reinstall it using chocolatey and follow other commands from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.

worked perfectly fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have installed react-native globally and still get the same try adding path of npm module (C:\Users\your user name\AppData\Roaming\npm) to system variables instead of user variables.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late, anyway

- Make sure you've added the path of the NPM in `system variable` rather than `user variable` in the `System Environment Variables`.

`PATH : C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Answer (score 0):

Open a the command prompt and type: `npm config list`:

[image]

Get the path underlined in red and add it your system path (change two back slashes into one), for example: `C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm`.

This solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote "react-native -v" to console to check have I still react-native and then just I wrote "react-native run-android" again and this time it worked. Yes just that. React native is terrible technology.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have uninstalled react native cli by mistake, I tried all answers mentioned above, but the below command worked for me.

> npx react-native run-android.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I was facing `'react-native' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file` error when I was running react-native start in VsCode.

I Solved it by running `npm install -g react-native-cli` in PowerShell

**Steps to follow**

1. run PowerShell as admin (important step)
2. run running `npm install -g react-native-cli` in PowerShell
3. close VsCode and rerun it
4. that's all!

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by running

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

then another error appears

> Command `run-android` unrecognized.

I fixed this error by

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

if you faced the same issue as me just type :

npm i react-native

then try to create a new project as its recommended by the react native doc by typing :
npx react-native init yourProjectName

this should resolve your problem

hope this was helpful