# Unable to resolve "./patternReg" from "node_modules\react-native-svg\lib\extract\extractProps.js

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

I am new in react native.
After install new library of react-native-svg-from-uri. and used in my component like

```
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';
<SvgUri width="200" height="200" source={require("./img/homer.svg")} />
```

when running my app it shows error

> Unable to resolve "./patternReg" from "node_modules\react-native-svg\lib\extract\extractProps.js.

now how to solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just installed react-native-svg to use the Victory charting package and am getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

I solve this runing this command:

```
npm i react-native-svg@^5.4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you created your App with `create-react-native-app`, then it was created with Expo, which already includes `react-native-svg`.

Try removing `react-native-svg` to avoid duplicate/mismatched dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed react-native-svg, looks like the library you are using require another module react-native-svg, try installing it and also **link** react-native-svg.

try following steps.

1> npm i react-native-svg

2> react-native link react-native-svg

3> npm install react-native-svg-uri --save

4> re-run the project

**Note: Make sure you have linked project correctly.**

Comment: Yes I have installed react-native-svg but when I run react-native link react-native-svg it shows this error "react-native : The term 'react-native' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ react-native link react-native-svg
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (react-native:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"

Comment: is react-native properly installed and all other environment properly setup? look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889487/react-native-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-pr

Comment: Yes I have installed properly

Comment: can you show me the imports from extractProps.js file
It can be found here -> (YOUR_POJECT)/node_modules/react-native-svg/lib/extract/extractProps.js.
And also check for the './patternReg' there, as I cannot find it in my extractProps.js file.

Comment: @RaviShankar here 

```import extractFill from "./extractFill";
import extractStroke from "./extractStroke";
import extractTransform, { props2transform } from "./extractTransform";
import extractClipPath from "./extractClipPath";
import extractResponder from "./extractResponder";
import extractOpacity from "./extractOpacity";
import { idPattern } from "../util";
```

There's no direct mention of the `./patternReg` in that directory at all.

Comment: can i have a look at your project @Fiid ?