# React Native, why is react-native run-android not working?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-jetifier

I'm trying to run command `react-native run-android` but it's throwing an error. I'm following docs I followed every step but it's not working, I think it's not picking the path but it set as shown in doc. Can Anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
(node:12536) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Launching emulator...
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Could not start emulator within 30 seconds..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. 

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

that's the error I'm getting after running react native in android

Comment: Try this link must help you [failed-to-run-jetifier-react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048978/failed-to-run-jetifier-react-native)

Comment: didn't worked why it's showing that `'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these.

1. Make sure JDK version is 8 or newer.
2. Make sure android path's are correctly set.
3. Remove android/build and android/app/build folders.

Edit:
If JDK version *is 14* and and gradle version is *less than 6.3* You have to either downgrade JDK to 11 or upgrade gradle to above 6.3

Comment: JDK version is 14, I set path correctly as per docs, build.grade one?

Comment: Ok, Jdk v14 has issues with gradle. I updated my answer.

Comment: I am glad it did :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your issue is related to: [How solve (Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache) issue in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60844245/how-solve-could-not-initialize-class-org-codehaus-groovy-reflection-reflectionc)

Also it says that you have RN has troubles launching an emulator. So you probably need to launch it yourself, or connect real device

Comment: RN lauch emulator but nothing happening after that it just throw error

Comment: and why that error `'C:\Users\Danger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`??

Comment: what node version are you using?

Comment: i'm using node v14.14.0

Comment: Have you setup all the paths correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48435909/10111123

Comment: yup  I added them. I read docs and i set them hoe they said  same