# I had followed the react-native docs for getting started but I'm stuck at launching the default App itself after running npx react-native run-android

Tags: android, react-native, npx

C:\Users\Xyz Choudhary\Test>npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 896 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Launching emulator...
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'C:\Users\Xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Could not start emulator within 30 seconds..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-7.1.-all.zip
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1981)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1577)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:87)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:67)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:68)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-7.1.-all.zip
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1981)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1577)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:87)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:67)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:68)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)

```
at makeError (C:\Users\Xyz Choudhary\Test\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\Xyz Choudhary\Test\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Xyz Choudhary\Test\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Xyz Choudhary\Test\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64442127/11647620

Comment: finally fixed the issues i have been facing

Answer (score 0):

**It May be failed due to dependency issues.**

Go to Your project directory and Delete  **node_modules** Folder.

After that open cmd and run this commands:

```
npm install or yarn install

npm start -- --reset-cache

npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

finally fixed the issues i have been facing first I downgraded the
**jdk 16** version to **jdk 15** and added it to enviroment variable path.

Then went to
**android\gradle-wrapper\gradle-wrapper-properties** (project folder) and changed the version to latest gradle version
**distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.-all.zip to distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip.**

and then went to **android\gradle-wrapper\build.gradle** (project folder) and changed the dependencies to latest plugin version
**classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0")**

After that finally the boilerplate of the project created ran using **npx react-native run-android**