# react-native: The term 'react-native' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've been trying to use custom fonts in my react-native app but I keep getting the error "react-native: The term 'react-native' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program" whenever I type ***react-native link*** to link my react-native.config.js file to my project. Any help please?

--I'm operating on Linux Mint

Comment: Have you looked at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889487/react-native-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-pr

Comment: Perfect! Just checked out the link you shared above and ***npx react-native link*** worked just like a charm!
Thanks heaps

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by running

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

then another error appears

> Command `run-android` unrecognized.

I fixed this error by

```
npm install
```

Hope this will fix your problem.